# How to Paginate after unwind in Spring boot with MongoDB?

Tags: spring, mongodb, pagination

I am currently encountering such a problem:

I have an object **A** which has an array property **Bs**. I would like to show Bs in the UI, but because there are too much data, I have to paginate somehow. The problem is, I did some research, but couldn't find a solution that can first unwind, then paginate.

**A:**

```
{
    id : 1,
    Bs : [{
        id: 29
    },{
        id : 3
    }]
}
```

If I use Aggregation, I can unwind the Bs, but can't paginate them afterwards. Pagination is the major problem.

If I use PagingAndSortingRepository, I can paginate, but can't unwind. Even if I unwind manually afterwards, because I paginated before unwind, the result won't be as desired.

If I use Query - Criteria, I can paginate with skip & limit, but still don't know how to unwind before pagination.

**THE BIG QUESTION:** How can I unwind first, then paginate the unwinded result?

**EDIT:**

Example data objects in MongoDB:

```
{
    id: 1,
    ts: 1488208130000,
    logs: [{
        id: 1,
        type: 4
    },{
        id: 2,
        type: 7
    }]
},
{
    id: 2,
    ts: 1488208150000,
    logs: [{
        id: 2,
        type: 4
    }]
}
```

I want to query `logs` with ts between startDate & endDate, desc via ts, also via `type` if specified. But there are too much data objects for example if you select last week ( they are coming 1 per sec nearly ), so I need pagination. I don't know how many logs will be in a data object. So, I can't paginate first, then unwind logs. The number probably won't match. I may query data collection 2. page with size 100, but when I unwind the logs, there may be 47 of them with the desired `type`.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually slice the array in mongo using the `$slice` operator.

E.g.

```
db.collection.findOne({_id:1}, {B: $slice: [start, end]})
```

You can do some pretty awesome things with it. Check the documentation for more examples: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/